# Printing the sum of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, sum

I am trying to print the sum of one line in a 2D array, but with this code nothing is returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>


double sum(double array[365][8], int i, int j)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for(i = 173; i <= 266; i++)
    {
        for(j = 2; j < 3; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + array[i][2];
        }
    }

    return (sum);

}

int main (void)
{
    int i, j;
    double array[365][8];


    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    for(i = 1; i <= 365; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%lf \n", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The sum is: %lf", sum(array, i, j));

    return (0);
}
```

I dont know what else to change to get it to work.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried running your program line by line in a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) while monitoring the values of all variables?

Comment: Why don't you test if `fopen` fails. If `fopen` fails and you continue, all bets are off. Did you debug this with your debugger? If you don't know how to user your debugger (learn it, it will save you a lot o time in the future), did you put some printfs in order to check what's going on? What do you mean by "Nothing is returned"? What is the output of your program?

Comment: The compiler doesn't bring up any errors

Comment: @TylerVis and when you _run_ the program? What is the output? Is there no output?

Comment: Test if `fopen` fails and right after `fscanf(file, "%lf \n", &array[i][j]);` put `printf("%lf\n", array[i][j]);` and see what happens.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Not checking for `EOF` or if a reading error has occurred after each and every `fscanf` is also risky after the check to `fopen`.

Comment: Reading beyond the bounds of the array inside the loops might give you the clue. Beside this, the whole `sum` function is a whole *mess* on its own. Try to alter it drastically.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes the file opens properly. There is not output:                                                Last login: Sun Mar 29 13:50:51 on ttys002
Kwasinds-MacBook-Air:~ tylervis$ /var/folders/pq/v1hcy2ds0z9dxnh19pfwwykh0000gq/T/geany_run_script_BC8EI0.sh ; exit;
/var/folders/pq/v1hcy2ds0z9dxnh19pfwwykh0000gq/T/geany_run_script_BC8EI0.sh: line 7: 41743 Abort trap: 6           "./question_5"


------------------
(program exited with code: 134)
Press return to continue

Comment: @TylerVis don't put essential information in comments, as you can see it's pretty unreadable. Instead [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking if `fopen` fails as @Jabberwocky said in comments.

I think the problem is most likely here:

you declare `double array[365][8]` but in this loop `for(i = 1; i <= 365; i++)` you are passing boundaries of your array.

I think this can help

```
    for(i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%lf \n", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

PS:then you should change other number based on this.